# Linear Independence and proving Span (B1) = Span (B2)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We let $$X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & -5 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$Let $B_1 = \{ I_3,2X,3X^2\}$, $B_2 = \{X^2,(X-I_3)^2,X^2+I_3\}$. Show that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are linearly independent sets and $span(B_1)=span(B_2)$.

The provided answer is:

[image]
Reviewing this answer I can't seem to understand how they concluded from $\{I, x , x^2\}$ that $B_1$ is also a linearly independent set.
Moreover, I also do not understand how they concluded that $span(B_1) = span(B_2)$.
Any help would be great, thank you so much!

Comment: Please replace the images of text by actual text, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset formulas, otherwise your question is not accessible for users with screen readers and can't be found using search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the vector space of your exercise, generated by the basis $C$.

For the first question the reason is that $C=\{I_3,X,X^2\}$ is a basis of $V$ (wa (?)) and for definition its vectors generate the space and they are linearly independents.
If we now take any of these three matrices ($M(3,\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb R^9$) multiplied by a scalar they still generate all the vector space because the direction of these three vectors  is the same of the vectors of $C$.
In your case, since the elements of $B_1=\{I_3,2X,3X^2\}$ are multiple of the elements of $C$, these keep being independent vectors and their linear combination generate the space $V$.
It's now easy to prove that $$\forall A_i \in B_2 \nexists \lambda_1,\lambda_2\in \mathbb R:A=\lambda_1 A_j+\lambda_2 A_k,$$ where $A_i,A_j,A_k$ are elements of $B_2$.
In conclusion,  $3=\text{dim(span}(B_1))=\text{dim(span}(B_2))=\text{dim(span}(V))$, so $B_1$ and $B_2$  generate $V$ because their number of linearly independent elements is the same of the dimension of $V$.